# Convert SQL query to laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5

Can anyone help me how to convert the SQL query to Larvel 5.2

First query (for current month)

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    customer_allocations 
WHERE 
    YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW());
```

Second query (for current week)

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    customer_allocations 
WHERE 
    WEEKOFYEAR(date) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW());
```

Third query (for current day)

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    customer_allocations 
WHERE 
    YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) AND 
    MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW()) AND 
    DAY(date) = DAY(NOW());
```

These SQL queries run successfully in phpmyadmin but I want to implement in laravel can anyone help me.

I have tried to convert these queries, but I get an error message on this line of code:

```
CustomerAllocation::where([YEAR('date'),'=',YEAR(NOW()),MONTH('date'),'=',
                            MONTH(NOW())])->get();
```

This is the error:

> Call to undefined function "App\Http\Controllers\YEAR()"

Comment: It should be `whereYear`,` whereMonth` ... Check this [link](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereYear)

Comment: can you convert any one query in to laravel

Comment: For your scenario, I think: `CustomerAllocation::whereDate('date', '=', date('Y-m-d'));` will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
CustomerAllocation::where([YEAR('date'),'=',YEAR(NOW()),MONTH('date'),'=',MONTH(NOW())])->get()
```

to

```
CustomerAllocation::whereRaw("YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW())")->whereRaw("MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW())")->get()
```

Use `whereRaw()`where you want put check custom condition like you want to do.